# In Docker-compose, don't see the host names of other services

Tags: docker, docker-compose, netcat

I'm trying to write an application which uses [Privoxy](https://www.privoxy.org/) and Tor as separate services in a Docker multi-container application. The directory, called `apkmirror-scraper-compose`, has the following structure:

```
.
├── docker-compose.yml
├── privoxy
│   ├── config
│   └── Dockerfile
├── scraper
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   ├── newnym.py
│   ├── requirements.txt
│   └── run.sh
└── tor
    └── Dockerfile
```

where the `docker-compose.yml` is

```
version: '3'

services:
  privoxy:
    build: ./privoxy
    links:
      - tor

  tor:
    build:
      context: ./tor
      args:
        password: "foo"

  scraper:
    build: ./scraper
    links:
      - tor
      - privoxy
```

where the `Dockerfile` in the `tor` directory is

```
FROM alpine:latest
EXPOSE 9050 9051
RUN apk --update add tor
RUN echo "ControlPort 9051" >> /etc/tor/torrc
ARG password
RUN echo "HashedControlPassword $(tor --quiet --hash-password $password)" >> /etc/tor/torrc
CMD ["tor"]
```

and that in `privoxy` is

```
FROM alpine:latest
EXPOSE 8118
RUN apk --update add privoxy
COPY config /etc/privoxy/config
CMD ["privoxy", "--no-daemon", "/etc/privoxy/config"]
```

Finally, the `Dockerfile` for `scraper` is

```
FROM python:2.7-alpine
ADD . /scraper
WORKDIR /scraper
COPY run.sh /scraper/run.sh
RUN chmod +x /scraper/run.sh
ENTRYPOINT /scraper/run.sh
```

where `run.sh` contains the single line

```
until nc -z tor 9050; do echo "Waiting for tor..." && sleep 1; done;
```

Basically, with the `nc -z` command, I'm waiting for the destination `tor` at port number `9050` to be listening. However, if I run `docker-compose build` followed by `docker-compose up`, I see the following:

```
Starting apkmirrorscrapercompose_tor_1
Starting apkmirrorscrapercompose_privoxy_1
Creating apkmirrorscrapercompose_scraper_1
Attaching to apkmirrorscrapercompose_tor_1, apkmirrorscrapercompose_privoxy_1, apkmirrorscrapercompose_scraper_1
tor_1      | May 02 15:10:02.757 [notice] Tor v0.2.8.12 running on Linux with Libevent 2.0.22-stable, OpenSSL LibreSSL 2.4.4 and Zlib 1.2.8.
tor_1      | May 02 15:10:02.757 [notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://www.torproject.org/download/download#warning
tor_1      | May 02 15:10:02.757 [notice] Read configuration file "/etc/tor/torrc".
privoxy_1  | 2017-05-02 15:10:03.250 7fb755a28b48 Info: Privoxy version 3.0.24
privoxy_1  | 2017-05-02 15:10:03.250 7fb755a28b48 Info: Program name: privoxy
tor_1      | May 02 15:10:02.781 [notice] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9050
tor_1      | May 02 15:10:02.781 [notice] Opening Control listener on 127.0.0.1:9051
tor_1      | May 02 15:10:02.000 [notice] Parsing GEOIP IPv4 file /usr/share/tor/geoip.
scraper_1  | Waiting for tor...
tor_1      | May 02 15:10:03.000 [notice] Parsing GEOIP IPv6 file /usr/share/tor/geoip6.
tor_1      | May 02 15:10:03.000 [warn] You are running Tor as root. You don't need to, and you probably shouldn't.
tor_1      | May 02 15:10:03.000 [notice] We were built to run on a 64-bit CPU, with OpenSSL 1.0.1 or later, but with a version of OpenSSL that apparently lacks accelerated support for the NIST P-224 and P-256 groups. Building openssl with such support (using the enable-ec_nistp_64_gcc_128 option when configuring it) would make ECDH much faster.
tor_1      | May 02 15:10:03.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 0%: Starting
tor_1      | May 02 15:10:03.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 80%: Connecting to the Tor network
tor_1      | May 02 15:10:04.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 85%: Finishing handshake with first hop
tor_1      | May 02 15:10:04.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 90%: Establishing a Tor circuit
tor_1      | May 02 15:10:04.000 [notice] Tor has successfully opened a circuit. Looks like client functionality is working.
tor_1      | May 02 15:10:04.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 100%: Done
scraper_1  | Waiting for tor...
scraper_1  | Waiting for tor...
scraper_1  | Waiting for tor...
scraper_1  | Waiting for tor...
scraper_1  | Waiting for tor...
scraper_1  | Waiting for tor...
```

where `Waiting for tor...` goes on indefinitely.

As I understand from https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#links, the "containers for the linked service will be reachable at a hostname identical to the alias, or the service name if no alias was specified". Since I have not specified an alias, the hostname should be `tor`, right? Can someone explain why this is not working?

Comment: Off the top of my head: Have you tried moving `EXPOSE 9050 9051` to under `docker-compose.yaml`?

Comment: try with `nc -l` instead of `nc -z`